# How do you get minecart hoppers to put items in chests?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

In Minecraft, I have tried to make minecart hoppers to put items in chests but it doesn't work. I haven't figured out a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly place a rail on a chest but you can place a rail on a hopper. Just make sure the hopper is not powered or it will not work.

Below I've included an Image on how to set it up

[image: Hopper Setup]

By the way, the rails don't have to be powered, but you can risk de-activating it using an activator rail.